# Connecting to different URLs in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am trying to implement solution to connect to second URL if first URL is down, what is the best and optimized way of connecting to the second URL? Currently, I am using the approach as:

1. Execute `AsyncTask` to execute `POST\GET` request
2. `onPostExecute`: If response has error message then again execute
   `AsyncTask` with different URL

Is this is valid, mature and optimized approach? Kindly, help.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Comment: use a `try...catch` and if u get a connection exception, then in the `catch` connect to the second URL

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check if your URL is reachable or not is :-

```
public boolean isReachable()

    {

        boolean reachable=false;
        try {
            reachable = InetAddress.getByName(host_name).isReachable(3000);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reachable;
    }
```

Here you can put url or host. instead of host_name. and Also you can define a timeOut. I just take 3 sec. as time out value.

Comment: I have entered url instead of hostname, it is giving me `false` result, but the url is opening from the web

Comment: Its just sending a ping request to your host ip address. You can test it with host name. So that it can get correct ip.